# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onPlayerReady (When using callback)

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to use `onPlayerReady()` and `onPlayerStateChange()` as call backs for my YT Iframe Api wrapper, but I can't seem to reference an instance of my wrapper. How do I go about using the call back to call an instance of my wrapper?  I have gotten my code to work when my functions are outside of my wrapper, but I would love to have them inside the wrapper.

#### Error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onPlayerReady
Player — player.self-7e1fbb555e29e354bc82162b755809f0b6435967f75b25c572d1953b57364c7c.js:12
onYouTubeIframeAPIReady — player.self-7e1fbb555e29e354bc82162b755809f0b6435967f75b25c572d1953b57364c7c.js:60
(anonymous function) — www-widgetapi.js:141:160
Global Code — www-widgetapi.js:141:215
jquery3.self-e200ee796ef24add7054280d843a80de75392557bb4248241e870fac0914c0c1.js:3842
```

#### CODE:

```
Helpers = window.Helpers || {};
Helpers.Google = Helpers.Google || {};
Helpers.Google.YT = Helpers.Google.YT || {};

Helpers.Google.YT = {

   Player: class Player {

    constructor(element = 'ytplayer', options = { playerVars: { controls: 1 },
                                                  height: '390',
                                                  width: '640',
                                                  videoId: 'novideoid',
                                                  events: {
                                                  'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                                                  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                                                }}, StubPlayerInstance = null ) {

      if (StubPlayerInstance == undefined) {
        this.player = new YT.Player(element, options);
      } else {
        this.player = StubPlayerInstance;
      }
    }

    loadVideoById($element) {
      var videoId = $element.data('video-id');
      var x = new String(videoId);
      this.player.loadVideoById(x);
    }

    init(modalId){
      const thatInstance = this;
      $(modalId).on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        thatInstance.loadVideoById($(e.relatedTarget));
      });  
      return this.player;    
    }

   onPlayerReady(event) {
     $('.open-popup').click(function() {
       event.target.playVideo();
     });
     $('.close-popup').click(function(e) {
       player.stopVideo();
     });
   }

   onPlayerStateChange(event) {
     if(event.data === 0) {           
       $('.close.close-popup').click();
     }
    }
  }
}

var player;


function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new Helpers.Google.YT.Player().init('#video-modal');
}
```

Comment: onPlayerReady is a class method not a standalone variable/function you would have to access it through some instance or prototype ie, `someInstance.onPlayerReady` or `Player.prototype.onPlayerReady`

Comment: when I try this.onPlayerReady or Player,.prototype.onPlayerReady, I can not access `this` (the current instance from the onPlayerReady method). But it does get called

Comment: It's not possible to reference the methods you want as default arguments in the constructor of the object they reside in. Try applying the default options within the body of the constructor, where you _do_ have access to `this`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'onReady': this.onPlayerReady.bind(this)
'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this)
```