# Expected spy click to have been called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, teaspoon

I am testing that the click event for an element is called in Jasmine-Teaspoon.  However, I am getting an error:

> "Expected spy click to have been called."

```
  describe("onPlayerStateChange", function(){
    it("should stop video when data equals to zero", function(){
      var closeElmeent = $(".close.close-popup");
      var spy = spyOn(closeElmeent, 'click');
      player.onPlayerStateChange(event);
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

See full code being tested here:

[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onPlayerReady (When using callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607184/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-onplayerready-when-using-callback)

Comment: Try putting `$(".close.close-popup")` in a variable and reusing it.  Repeated jQuery invocations of the same selector do not return the same object.

Comment: @Taplar that actually works for the initial code I posted, but I just updated because my code is actually a little different. Hope you know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the context from the linked question:

```
onPlayerStateChange(event) {
 if(event.data === 0) {           
   $('.close.close-popup').click();
 }
}
```

Is event.data set to 0? Because undefined is not equal to zero: false === (undefined === 0)

```
describe('onPlayerStateChange', () => {
    it('should stop video when data equals to zero', () => {
        event.data = 0;
        const closeElmeent = $(".close.close-popup");
        const spy = spyOn(closeElmeent, 'click'); // if you want it to actually click, you can use "spyOn(closeElmeent, 'click').and.callThrough();"
        onplayerStateChange(event);
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, event was set to 0, I ended up using dependency injection to solve it.